# Azure Storage Blob Rest Api Headers

Tags: c#, azure, windows-8, azure-storage

I can't upload image to my azure storage by REST API.
This is my code:

```
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            using (var fileStream = await _eventPhoto.OpenStreamForReadAsync())
            {
                var content = new StreamContent(fileStream);
                content.Headers.Add("Content-Type", _eventPhoto.ContentType);
                content.Headers.Add("x-ms-blob-type", "BlockBlob");

                var uploadResponse = await client.PutAsync(new Uri("https://myservice.blob.core.windows.net/photos/newblob"),content);
                int x = 2;
            }
        }
```

I get error about missing paramerer. Probably Authorization.

1) How to add missing headers?

2) Someone have working sample?

3) How to add Authorization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a reason not to be using the client library that does this for you already?  If you have a reason and you *really* want to use HttpClient, then you need to either a.) implement signing [per spec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179428.aspx), or b.) use a [Shared Access Signature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179428.aspx) in your URI.

Comment: I using Windows 8 app. One way is only rest api.

Comment: What's wrong with the Runtime client?  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2012/11/05/windows-azure-storage-client-library-for-windows-runtime.aspx

Comment: I have error when place using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob. I added library.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace AzureSharedKey
{
    class Program
    {
        private const string blobStorageAccount = "your_account";
        private const string blobStorageAccessKey = "your_access_key";
        private const string blobPath = "blob_path";
        private const string blobContainer = "your_container";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Program Initiated..");
            CreateContainer();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        private async static void CreateContainer()
        {
            string requestMethod = "GET";
            string msVersion = "2016-05-31";
            string date = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("R", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            string clientRequestId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            string canHeaders = string.Format("x-ms-client-request-id:{0}\nx-ms-date:{1}\nx-ms-version:{2}", clientRequestId, date, msVersion);
            string canResource = string.Format("/{0}/{1}/{2}", blobStorageAccount, blobContainer, blobPath);
            string SignStr = string.Format("{0}\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n{1}\n{2}", requestMethod, canHeaders, canResource);
            string auth = CreateAuthString(SignStr);
            string urlPath = string.Format("https://{0}.blob.core.windows.net/{1}/{2}", blobStorageAccount, blobContainer, blobPath);
            Uri uri = new Uri(urlPath);
            Console.WriteLine("urlPath  "+ urlPath);
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-ms-date", date);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-ms-version", "2016-05-31");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-ms-client-request-id", clientRequestId);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", auth);

            HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(uri).Result;
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                string actualFilename= Path.GetFileName(blobPath);
                string physicaPath = "D:/Others/AZ/";//change path to where you want to write the file
                HttpContent content = response.Content;
                string pathName = Path.GetFullPath(physicaPath + actualFilename);
                FileStream fileStream = null;
                try
                {
                    fileStream = new FileStream(pathName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
                    await content.CopyToAsync(fileStream).ContinueWith(
                       (copyTask) =>
                       {
                           fileStream.Close();
                       });
                    Console.WriteLine("FileName: "+actualFilename);
                    Console.WriteLine("File Saved Successfully..");
                }
                catch
                {
                    if (fileStream != null) fileStream.Close();
                    throw;
                }

            }
            else
            {
                throw new FileNotFoundException();
            }
        }

        private static string CreateAuthString(string SignStr)
        {
            string signature = string.Empty;
            byte[] unicodeKey = Convert.FromBase64String(blobStorageAccessKey);
            using (HMACSHA256 hmacSha256 = new HMACSHA256(unicodeKey))
            {
                byte[] dataToHmac = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(SignStr);
                signature = Convert.ToBase64String(hmacSha256.ComputeHash(dataToHmac));
            }

            string authorizationHeader = string.Format(
                  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                  "{0} {1}:{2}",
                  "SharedKey",
                  blobStorageAccount,
                  signature);

            return authorizationHeader;
        }
    }
}
```

this code worked for me

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. For a useful answer you should explain your code a little bit more.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this example.

http://www.codeninjango.com/programming/azure/azure-blob-storage-rest-api/

It gives a step by step guide to using the Azure Blob Storage REST API to upload chunked files with SAS url's.